# Pop method for doubly linked list implementation in C, do I need to use free

Tags: c, list, struct

As a beginner with C, I'm very unsure when I should be using free. I'm working on a pop method which removes an element from the end of a list. It should also return the value of the element removed.

Here are my `List` and `ListNode` structs

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
    void *value;
} ListNode;

typedef struct List {
    int count;
    ListNode *first;
    ListNode *last;
} List;
```

Heres the code for my `remove_from_back` function.

```
void *remove_from_back(List *list)
{
    void *result = NULL;

    if (list->last == NULL) return result;

    result = list->last->value;
    if (list->last->value == list->first->value) {
        list->last = list->first = NULL;    
    } else {
        list->last = list->last->prev;
        list->last->next = NULL;        
    }   
    return result;
}
```

add_to_back function which creates the memory for the nodes

```
void add_to_back(List *list, void *value)
{  
    ListNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(ListNode));
    node->value = value;

    if (list->first == NULL) {
        list->first = node;
        list->last = node;
    } else {
        list->last->next = node;
        node->prev = list->last;
        list->last = node;
    }

    list->count++;
}
```

Comment: You mention C, whereas [`delete`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/) is a C++ operator. If your node was allocated with [`malloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) then use [`free`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) to free it. In general, leave it to whoever allocated the node to free it, don't make it part of your function.

Comment: Never. delete doesn't exist in c. Maybe you mean free ()?

Comment: Yes thanks guys, I updated the question. @Jens can you expand on that? If I have a function removing nodes, why shouldn't I have this function be freeing the node I'm removing?

Comment: Fyi...you are dereferencing  a null a pointer twice in your remove function.

Comment: @DanielKobe: Because I think it's bad form to do more in a function than advertised: what the function does (as stated by its name) is to remove the last node from the list. Not free its memory. You could introduce a function `remove_from_back_and_free()` if you desired to remove a node *and* free the node's memory.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the caller allocated the memory, they should free the memory.  If your container allocated it internally, then it should free the memory.  Create your function interface to suit exactly one of these conventions, but don't mix them.  To elaborate on this, I'll give an example from C++ where a stack container manages its own memory.  To deal with that in a nice way, `pop` doesn't return a value.  It just removes it and deallocates.  If you want the value that will be popped, you use `top` _before_ calling `pop`.

Comment: As written, your `remove_from_back` returns the _value_. So, it _must_ do the `free`, as otherwise, the removal is a memory leak. A _caller_ would _not_ know what node to free [`list->last` after return is already the wrong value for that]. If `remove_from_back` had returned `ListNode *` [filled from `list->last`], you could set up the _caller_ to do the `free` [after the _caller_ is done with it]

Comment: @CraigEstey: It doesn't have to be a leak, depending on how it's being allocated. There is not enough context to make that judgement.

Comment: @Jens It has to be a leak in all probability, based upon any reasonable usage/implementation. Otherwise, _every_ caller for the `remove` function would have to snoop/save `list->last` before the call, which is error prone and unlikely. Caller _can't_ free before the call and after the call `list->last` has the _wrong_ value to free, so caller could _not_ do: `val = remove(list); free(list->last)`. Even if nodes are _not_ alloc'ed (e.g. `ListNode nodepool[1000]`), the program still loses control of the popped node.

Comment: I'm very confused as to how to stop the memory leaks. @Jens are you saying I should have a seperate function for freeing nodes? I've add the `add_to_back` function I created which handles `calloc` to creates the nodes so are you saying I should add the freeing to this function? That doesnt really make sense to me. @CraigEstey would you mind showing me how you would free the memory in my function?

Comment: @DanielKobe: As I said in my earlier comment, there isn't enough context in your question to give sound advice on how/where you should handle allocation and free. If you have a function `add_to_back` which allocates and adds a node, then it makes sense to have a function `remove_from_back` which removes and frees a node. In that case, ownership of memory management is your list implementation, not the user of your list. See paddy's comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `add_to_back()` function allocated the memory for the node, the `remove_from_back()` function should delete the memory for the node.  It should not release the data that the node points at, though.  Thus:

```
void *remove_from_back(List *list)
{
    void *result = NULL;

    if (list->last == NULL) return result;

    ListNode *dead = list->last;            // Added
    result = list->last->value;
    if (list->last->value == list->first->value) {
        list->last = list->first = NULL;    
    } else {
        list->last = list->last->prev;
        list->last->next = NULL;        
    } 
    free(dead);                             // Added
    return result;
}
```

I have added just two lines.  I have not changed any of the intermediate lines, so if there are bugs in the original code, those bugs are in the revised code too.
But the added lines prevent leakage of the node that was allocated when the data was added to the list.

When you allocate memory, you need to know where the corresponding `free()` will take place.  If you don't know, you need to make a decision about how it will be freed and implement the freeing mechanism.  Sometimes, you can make a decision that it doesn't matter — the program is about to exit anyway.  But reusable code can seldom justify that assumption.  It's like opening and closing files — you can neglect closing files, but eventually you run into problems with too many open files.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a pop method would remove an element from a data structure and return a pointer to it. Then you would perform some operation on the element such as extracting a value and/or possibly freeing the memory allocated to the element. In your example, which is not typical, you are most likely leaking memory. You lose all reference to the node being popped.

If you need to free the node than I would modify the code to handle that.

```
if (list->last == list->first)
{
     free (list->last);
     list->last = list->first = NULL; 
}
else 
{ 
    ListNode * temp = list->last;
    list->last = list->last->prev; 
    list->last->next = NULL;
    free (temp);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to properly free the node? Also where am I derefrencing a NULL value, sorry if that sounds like a dumb question.

Comment: I don't see the dereference anymore. I am guessing an edit happened at some point.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to free your mallocs. If you are working with Linux, use valgrind to check what happens to memory.

[image: valgrind Summary]

I have posted here my program's output with valgrind. As you can see, I used 6 allocs and freed 5(only to show you :)).

And you can also see I lost 100 bytes since I did not free one alloc.

Now, think yourself what will happen if we don't free our allocs.